# How to create site which in IE=11 uses edge mode and in others IE use IE=6

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, meta-tags, internet-explorer-11

This is really hard question. I need to open page in IE11 with edge mode and in others IE (11,10,9,8) i need to run page with IE6 mode.
I tried to use

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,IE=6" />
```

tried to use

```
<!--[IF LT IE 10]>
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=6" />
<![ENDIF]-->
```

even tried to change meta attribute with javascript and nothing works.

pls help

Comment: ***IE6 mode***?!?! NOOOoooooooo.......!

Comment: _(1)_ This is a terrible idea and shouldn't be done. _(2)_ You can't run ***IE 11*** in ***edge*** mode and in ***IE 6*** mode.

Comment: IE10 dropped support for conditional comments, so I don't think there's any way you can use markup to distinguish IE10 from IE11. You should be able to use `<!-- [if lte IE 9]>` to target IE 9 and below.

Comment: What could possibly be the use case for this? **I guarantee there is a better solution than this.**

Answer (score 1):

I would strongly advise not forcing IE10 through IE8 to behave as though they are a seriously non-standards-compliant browser from 2001.

But if you really have a case for needing to do that, I expect the venerable (and otherwise-to-be-avoided) `document.write` could do it for you:

```
<head>
<script>
if (thisIsIE()) {
    document.write(
        '<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=' +
        thisIsIE11() ? "edge" : "6" +
        '">'
    );
}
</script>
```

Of course, you can't do that in XHTML.

Alternately, detect server-side and vary what you send back.

And again, really, if you can possibly avoid doing this (and you almost certainly can)...